# Insert KeepNext by using .insertOoxml

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-addins

Beginner here. I'm working on a project to create a Word Add-In using Office Javascript API by using Script Lab.

I have trouble to edit content by using .insertOoxml. In particular, I would like to create a function to keep all paragraphs in my selection on the same page.

Since there is no (to my knowledge) specific method for it in the paragraph object, I'm trying to insert a <w:keepNext/> part directly in my XML file by using the ".insertOoxml" method. The problem is that no matter where I'm inserting the <w:keepNext/> part, it doesn't insert it in my document.

To start, I'm using the sample provided by MS for the .insertOoxml method but I'm open to any other solution to achieve this.

Thanks a lot,

Sebastien

```
// Link to full sample: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/prod/samples/word/50-document/manage-body.yaml
// Inserts OOXML at the beginning of this document.
// Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
await Word.run(async (context) => {

  // Create a proxy object for the document body.
  const body = context.document.body;

  // Queue a command to insert OOXML at the beginning of the body.
  body.insertOoxml(
    "<pkg:package xmlns:pkg='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage'><pkg:part pkg:name='/_rels/.rels' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml' pkg:padding='512'><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships'><Relationship Id='rId1' Type='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument' Target='word/document.xml'/></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name='/word/document.xml' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml'><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' ><w:body><w:p><w:pPr>**<w:keepNext/>**<w:spacing w:before='360' w:after='0' w:line='480' w:lineRule='auto'/><w:rPr><w:color w:val='70AD47' w:themeColor='accent6'/><w:sz w:val='28'/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:color w:val='70AD47' w:themeColor='accent6'/><w:sz w:val='28'/></w:rPr><w:t>This text has formatting directly applied to achieve its font size, color, line spacing, and paragraph spacing.</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>",
    Word.InsertLocation.start
  );

  // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
  await context.sync();

  console.log("Added OOXML to the beginning of the document body.");
});

// Read "Understand when and how to use Office Open XML in your Word add-in" for guidance on working with OOXML.
// https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml

// The Word-Add-in-DocumentAssembly sample shows how you can use this API to assemble a document.
// https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-DocumentAssembly
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS this is probably happening because of what happens when Word inserts one document into another (which is in effect what your code is doing).

Let's say the document into which you are inserting your XML is empty. In that case, even though it is "empty", there is already a "paragraph" (because every Word document has at least one paragraph in at least one Word Section), and Word tries not to create an extra one. So in effect Word is just modifying the text of the existing final paragraph of the document, so discards Paragraph Run properties such as Keep With Next.

If you modify your XML so that you add an extra empty paragraph after this paragraph (e.g. you put a `<w:p/>` element immediately before the </w:body> tag), word correctly retains the Keep with next ( `<w:keepNext/>` ) element.

But then it adds a paragraph that you probably don't want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll look into that and let you know if it worked.